# return the first 3 results beginning with letter (a-z)

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a query that would return the first three results beginning with letter (a-z)? I don't mean the first three results of one letter, but the first three results of all letters (a-z) in alphabetical order.

So let's say I have a table with this names:

```
id  name
1   Abe 
2   Andy
3   Asad
4   Azizi
5   Berta
6   Bulma
7   Caan
8   Carl
9   Cesar
10  Coby
11  Dimitri
```

and would like to get this result from a query (first three starting with letter)

```
id  name
1   Abe 
2   Andy
3   Asad
4   Berta
5   Bulma
6   Caan
7   Carl
8   Cesar
9   Dimitri
```

Comment: To answer the question you pose, **Yes** it is possible. But you should edit your question and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` (MySQL 8.0+/MariaDB):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UPPER(LEFT(Name,1))
                    ORDER BY name) AS rn
     FROM tab
) sub
WHERE rn <=3
ORDER BY name;
```

**[DB-Fiddle.com Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iQZbWDkYmQrh3ydygpTUJZ/1)**

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=2e723e78f250f3678e41181838cde2a2)**